# Defining my conceptual model

Tags: interaction, predictor, mediation, dependent-variable

How can I define my conceptual model in terms of independent/dependent and moderating/mediating variables?

My research topic is about anthropomorfism and how it can reduce food waste. My research is focused on how anthropomorfism can be used on misshapen fruits and vegetables to increase the probability consumers will buy these products. I will also add the country characteristic individualism vs collectivsm as a variable that influence whether or not consumers are more prone to anthropomorphism and prone to more pro environmental behavior in the first place (moderator or mediator).

I am currently struggling with how to summarize this in a conceptual model that explains the variables and their relation to each other. Would somebody be able to make this a bit clearer to me?

Comment: Were you thinking of converting your description into what soem people call a logic model? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_model

Comment: anthropomorfism ? Is that the same as Anthropomorphism - [the attribution of human traits, emotions, or intentions to non-human entities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthropomorphism). I don't understand how "consumers are more prone to anthropomorphism" ?